# LocalStorage getItem and Loop Values

Tags: javascript, html, loops, local-storage

I am storing some values into local storage using the following line of code;

```
localStorage.setItem(event.lastEventId, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Looking at the browser console, the storage looks like this;

[image]

I want to loop through the localstorage and display the **values**.

The loop I have so far is;

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  $("#result").prepend("New transaction " + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + "<br>");
}
```

The `#result` displays the following;

> New transaction {"TimeStamp":"2017-08-18
> 16:34:15","Direction":"Out","CardNo":"40160433","SerialNo":20559458}
>
> New transaction {"TimeStamp":"2017-08-18
> 16:34:55","Direction":"In","CardNo":"40160432","SerialNo":20559459}

I want to display the values only, not associated keys. For example;

> New transaction 2017-08-18
> 16:34:15, Out, 40160433, 20559458
>
> New transaction 2017-08-18
> 16:34:55, In, 40160432, 20559459

What do I need to change in order to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns you a string. So in order to achieve what you want, you need to parse the returned string in JSON and extract the values. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
    $("#result").prepend("New transaction " + data.TimeStamp + ", " + \ 
         data. Out + ", " + data. CardNo + ", " + data. SerialNo + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Parse the data, and
2. Loop through the resulting object showing only the *values* of its properties, and
3. Join those together into a string in some way, perhaps with `,` in-between

For instance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
  var str = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return obj[key]; }).join(", ");
  $("#result").prepend("New transaction " + str + "<br>");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// The string from local storage
var stringFromLocalStorage = '{"TimeStamp":"2017-08-18 16:34:15","Direction":"Out","CardNo":"40160433","SerialNo":20559458}';

var obj = JSON.parse(stringFromLocalStorage);
var str = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return obj[key]; }).join(", ");
$("#result").prepend("New transaction " + str + "<br>");
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, of course, hardcode the property names if your structure is static.